# What is preventing my page from being horizontally centered?

Tags: html, css

The picture, description, ingredients, and steps are all under the `<div class="content">` with this css:

```
.content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```

but my content still shows up on the left side of the page. What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```css
html {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.header {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

img {
    width: 350px;
    /* height: auto; */
}

.item img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
}

.content-home {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: auto;
}

.content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.item {
    height: 600px;
    margin: 12px;

    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-basis: 220px;
    text-align: center;
}

.left {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.left img {
    /* padding-left: 30px; */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    padding-top: 23px;
}

.top-right {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-left: 60px;
    padding-right: 80px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    border-top: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.spaghettiHeader {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

.gyudonHeader {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

.calderetaHeader {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

.description {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border: 10px;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Spaghetti Aglio, Olio, e Peperoncino con Bottarga</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../index.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="spaghettiHeader">
        <h1>Spaghetti Aglio, Olio, e Peperoncino con Bottarga</h1>
    </div>
    
    <div class="content">
        <div class="left">
            <img src="../photos/spaghettiAglio1200x1800.jpeg">
        </div>
    
        <div class="top-right description">
            <h2>Description</h2>
            <p> Muggine bottarga (cured mullet roe) is an ancient traditional food from the island of Sardinia in Italy. 
            I have enjoyed this treat for so many years I just had to share it with you. A classic pasta dish from Italy 
            becomes a specialty by adding bottarga to it. Enjoy!
            </p>
            

            <h3>Ingredients</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>1 (16 ounce) package spaghetti</li>
                <li>¼ cup extra-virgin olive oil, or more to taste</li>
                <li>2 cloves garlic, minced</li>
                <li>1 red chile pepper, seeded and minced</li>
                <li>2 ounces grated Sardinian mullet bottarga, divided</li>
                <li>4 tablespoons chopped flat-leaf (Italian) parsley</li>
                <li>1 small lemon, zested</li>
            </ul>
            <h3>Steps</h3>
            <ol>
                <li>Bring a large pot of lightly salted water to a boil. Cook spaghetti in the boiling water, stirring occasionally, until tender yet firm to the bite, about 12 minutes.</li>
                <li>Meanwhile, heat oil in a large skillet or wok over medium heat.</li>
                <li>Add garlic to the oil and cook until just warmed through, 1 to 2 minutes. Add chile pepper and stir together, reducing the temperature to medium-low. Continue stirring. The garlic should never become dark brown or crispy. If this has happened, the garlic is burnt and no longer appropriate for consumption.</li>
                <li>Drain the pasta, reserving at least 1 cup pasta water. Add the spaghetti to the oil mixture, still on medium-low heat. Stir or toss until all the spaghetti is well coated. Add 3/4 of the bottarga and stir to mix with the spaghetti, adding the reserved pasta water to hydrate as needed. There should be a little "sauce" when serving but not soupy.</li>
                <li>Divide onto 4 plates and sprinkle with chopped parsley and lemon zest; squeeze lemon juice over and sprinkle remaining bottarga on top right before serving.</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="home-button">
        <a href="../index.html">home</a>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

this is what the page looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYudF.jpg

Comment: Hi! but all content is center align.

Comment: I can't see an element with *class content*

Comment: Sorry, i'm an idiot. I posted the html code for my home page instead of the page that I meant to post. The code is now updated!

Answer (score 0):

By default `display: flex` shows content in 'row' direction which results in the layout you got.

To correct this issue, you can either:

1. change the flex-direction from **row** to **column** by

   **flex-direction : column;** in the content CSS
2. change the display type of .content element from **flex** to **block**

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! I don't think I was super clear in my question but I would like to keep my content layout as is, i'm more looking to figure out how to shift all of the content(photo + text) over to the right a little bit so that it is centered. As of right now it is shifted to the left more than centered.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `text-align: center;` in .content

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! Adding text-align: center will change the layout of the text. I probably wasn't clear in my question but I would like to keep my text alignment the same but shift all of the content(photo + text) over to the right a little so that it is centered on the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center the text inside `content` class, you can add `text-align: center` in the `content` class.
It will became like this:

```
.content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    text-align: center;
}
```

`align-items` and `justify-content` only adjust your content's inside tag. While the `<div>` tag inside `content` class didn't have their `width` adjusted. So by default, they're set as `width: 100%`;

Try to adjust your `<div>` width to learn more about their interaction.
[Flexbox Example](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! I may not have been clear in my question but I would like to keep the text alignment and layout as is, but shift all content(photo + text) over to the right a little so that it is centered. Basically exactly how the graphic for justify-content: center; is in the link that you included.